# Systemd unit start vs enable

Tags: systemd, startup

Can someone clarify for me difference between *"enable"* and *"start"* for a systemd unit. I have been told that if a unit has an [Install] section, then `enable` should be called, otherwise just `start` is enough.

How this handled in startup process? Systemd automagically makes right decision?

Comment: Systemd/systemctl does not have an `activate` command, do you mean `start`?

Comment: Yeap, start - for activate.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To `start` (activate) a service , you will run the command `systemctl start my_service.service`, this will start the service immediately in the current session.

To `enable` a service at boot , you will run `systemctl enable my_service.service` .

> [**Enable**](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#Unit%20File%20Commands) one or more units or unit instances. This will create a set of symlinks, as encoded in the "[Install]" sections of the indicated unit files. After the symlinks have been created, the system manager configuration is reloaded (in a way equivalent to daemon-reload), in order to ensure the changes are taken into account immediately

The `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` contains `init` scripts , when you type `systemctl enable` to start a service at boot it will be linked to `/etc/systemd/system/`.

```
#systemctl enable my_service.service
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/my_service.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/my_service.service'
```

Comment: under "init scripts" you mean unit files ?

Answer (score 12):

`systemctl enable` configures the system to start the service at next reboot (with caveats around correct target states, etc).

`systemctl start` starts (activates) the service immediately.

So if you want a service to start now and on every reboot then you need to both `enable` *and* `start` the service.

Comment: The last sentence is not true: `systemctl enable --now` will both start and enable a unit.

Comment: I really wish this showed in `systemctl --help`. It's in the manpage, but buried in a paragraph, which is not usually how subcommand options are listed in manpages. I always struggle to locate this option as I don't need it often and never seem to remember if it's a `systemctl start` or `systemctl enable` option. :-/