# One systemctl command to both start and enable

Tags: shell-script, systemd, startup, systemctl

Using one command to both start and enable `systemctl` managed software would be useful to spare a few lines in a few scripts, making them a bit more aesthetic (not really a problem but a nice thing to have).

Is there one `systemctl` command to both `start` and `enable` a program controlled by `systemctl`?

Comment: Relating-only: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/374280/117549

Comment: Yeah, it has been discussed in several places like the post Jeff linked to or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47715/22142)... even [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302261/systemd-unit-activate-vs-enable#comment530710_302267) etc...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, there is, [since systemd 220](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/dde8bb32b12c855509777ce52ff59a835155ac78/NEWS#L144) (May 2015):

```
systemctl enable --now
```

This will enable and start the named units. See [the `systemctl` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#enable%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) for details.